# Is it possible, good practice, to add comments to Info.Plist, or entitlements in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist, entitlements

I'm working with Xamarin and Xcode, and am looking for any documentation that says it's possible to add comments to either of these files, or advice that I shouldn't even attempt it.  (e.g. b/c it breaks some version of ios)

Is it possible (or wise) to add comments into these files?

Comment: Try it. Build your app. Archive it. Then extract the final Info.plist from the archived app. The comments may not survive the build so it wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to add comments using the standard XML comments syntax, for example:

```
<!--We need to define aps-environment because... -->
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>
```

And of course it is good practice to add explanatory comments to any non-obvious code, just as with every source code file.

Comment: If you edit a .plist file with PlistBuddy, all XML comments will be stripped out.